# Reactive WebClient of non-reactive remote server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Is there any difference between calling non-reactive and reactive remote web services from the Spring Webflux reactive client's point of view in following example?

Client:

```
Flux<String> stringFlux = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/strings")
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class);
```

Reactive service, producing regular "text/plain", not "text/event-stream":

```
@GetMapping("/strings")
Flux<String> stringFlux() {
    return Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
}
```

And "traditional" MVC service:

```
@GetMapping("/strings")
List<String> stringList() {
    return List.of("a", "b", "c");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Without `application/stream+json` or similar content type, Flux is treated and serialized like an ordinary list.